# Why does elm-make takes 20+ seconds in dev env, even when just adding whitespace to a file

Tags: performance, development-environment, elm, elm-make

## Steps to reproduce this issue

- Instructions to Build and start local webpack devser:
  https://github.com/jigargosar/elm-simple-gtd#build-instructions
- touch src/elm/Mat.elm
- compilation time 20+sec (find output and hardware spec below)
- note: when modifying any other file, it takes around 7sec.

## Steps already taken towards speeding up compilation time

- I have been working on solving this puzzle since 2.5 weeks
- Initially time taken to compile was 60+ seconds,
- Current compilation time was achieved by:

  - reducing any direct dependency on Msg.elm, Now Msg.elm is imported only in two places Main.elm and Update.elm
  - And by minimizing the number of direct case expressions on Msg by splitting them into Sub messages.
  - [Output](https://github.com/jigargosar/elm-simple-gtd/blob/master/grep-case-expressions.elm) of `grep -B 1 -A 22 "case " src/elm/**.elm  >
    case-expressions.elm`

## Expected Solution

- Some way to speed up coding to feedback time.
- Right now it feels like I am doing web-development in java :(

## Hardware Overview:

- Model Name:   MacBook Pro
- Model Identifier:   MacBookPro11,3
- Processor Name: Intel Core i7
- Processor Speed:    2.3 GHz
- Number of Processors:   1
- Total Number of Cores:  4
- L2 Cache (per Core):    256 KB
- L3 Cache:   6 MB
- Memory: 16 GB

## Webpack Output after `touch src/elm/Mat.elm`

```
webpack: Compiling...
Started compiling Elm..
Running elm-make /Users/jigargosar/GitHub/elm-simple-gtd/src/elm/Main.elm --yes --output /var/folders/29/6bhf11s93lq2_qh4xqngyxq00000gn/T/117623-37848-izmzom.wdmz.js
Success! Compiled 16 modules.
Successfully generated /var/folders/29/6bhf11s93lq2_qh4xqngyxq00000gn/T/117623-37848-izmzom.wdmz.js

Time Taken: 21s
Hash: 38c3886d59302e0c24be
Version: webpack 3.3.0
Time: 23220ms
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

## Webpack Output after `touch src/elm/GroupDoc/View.elm`

```
webpack: Compiling...
Started compiling Elm..
Running elm-make /Users/jigargosar/GitHub/elm-simple-gtd/src/elm/Main.elm --yes --output /var/folders/29/6bhf11s93lq2_qh4xqngyxq00000gn/T/117623-37848-emkx7h.sklbj.js
Time Taken: 8.0s
Success! Compiled 5 modules.
Successfully generated /var/folders/29/6bhf11s93lq2_qh4xqngyxq00000gn/T/117623-37848-emkx7h.sklbj.js

Hash: 2d9089e293e0ad52491e
Version: webpack 3.3.0
Time: 10243ms
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: Have you tried running the build with verbose print out? Have you tried anything yourself to solve this puzzle?

Comment: Does your code have large case ... of expressions with lots of different patterns to match? This tends to increase compile time.

Comment: Edit your question instead dumping stuff into comments please.

Comment: @GhostCat I have updated the question with "Steps already taken towards speeding up compilation time" and "output of grep case expressions". Apologies for dumping part of my response in comments.